# Неоправданный The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: java, android

Я понимаю как переводится "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.". И я стал стирать коды чтобы найти ту самую тяжелую часть кода. Но к сожалению не получилось. Смотрите сами

Лог:

```
04-29 21:56:03.503 895-895/some.package I/Choreographer: Skipped 60 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-29 21:56:03.534 1544-1565/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed some.package/.activity.LoginActivity: +1s283ms
04-29 21:56:04.038 895-895/some.package I/Choreographer: Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

FC_load fc;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.tagwishes.fc.R.layout.activity_main);

    fc = new FC_load();
    fc.execute();
}

class FC_load extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // session manager
        SessionManager session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
            // SqLite database handler
            SQLiteHandler db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
            db.deleteUsers();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Intent intent;

        if (result) {
            // Launching the login activity
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
        } else {
            // Launching the login activity
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        }

        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

LoginActivity

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(com.tagwishes.fc.R.layout.activity_login);
    }
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Я бы просто проигнорировал это)

Comment: Боюсь вы привели не весь код необходимый для понимания вашей проблемы, судя по логу проблема у вас в LoginActivity, но как она у вас вызывается и что делает из кода не видно.

Comment: intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
Вот так вызывается.
А у LoginActivity.class ничего. Пустой экран

Comment: А если убрать `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);?

Comment: Это не имеет значения, оно выполняется не на UI. Ради проверки убрал, не помогло